# Are there any services offering blockchain.info-like API for multiple currencies?

Tags: api, altcoin, services, blockchain-explorer

I am wondering whether there are any services that offer some API like blockchain.info does but for multiple currencies at the same time. I know there are a lot of block explorers out there, but they appear to be disjointed and focused on one currency at a time.

Answer (score 2):

[BlockCypher](http://www.blockcypher.com) is adding support for Litecoin, we're currently downloading the LTC block chain and will put it out next week. All the  [Bitcoin APIs](http://dev.blockcypher.com/) will work in the same way for Litecoin.